# Two post options in one form in PHP — is it possible?

Tags: php, html, forms

Is there any way to write two action option together ? As a example :

```
<?php

echo '<html>';
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="form_action" value="1">';
echo '<input class=submit type="submit" value="[PUSH IT]" name="Submit">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="action2" value="1">';
echo '<input class=submit type="submit" value="[AGAIN]" name="Submit">';
echo '</form>';
echo '</html>';

?>
```

But maybe here are some problems, because when anyone submits the form by clicking one button, it will show the result of two buttons together. But submit buttons show up horizontally.
But in two different forms, submit buttons will show up vertically. So, is there any way to show two submit buttons inside different form horizontally?

Comment: yes, just keep them in a separate forms, and please don't torture php to echo out so much of HTML

Comment: But it will show vertically. But is there any way to show it horizontally ?

Comment: @slash-bang Use `display: inline-block;`

Comment: if you want to go oldschool, a <table> would simplify the alignment issue.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better separate them to two forms.

```
<?php
echo '<html>';
echo '<FORM action=""  method="post">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="form_action" value="1">';
echo '<INPUT class=submit type="submit" value="[PUSH IT]" name="Submit">';
echo '</FORM>';
echo '<FORM action="" method="post"'>
echo '<input type="hidden" name="action2" value="1">';
echo '<INPUT class=submit type="submit" value="[AGAIN]" name="Submit">';
echo '</FORM>';
echo '</html>';
// Rest of the code
?>
```

and for your own sake you'd better switch to HTML without using `echo` all the time

```
//...some PHP code
?>
<!-- now put all raw HTML here -->
<html>
<form action=""  method="post">
//...
<?php
// now, put your PHP code.
```

If you want to place both forms horizontally you should do it in CSS.

```
<FORM action=""  method="post" style="display: inline-block">
<!-- ... -->
</form>
<FORM action=""  method="post" style="display: inline-block">
<!-- ... -->
</form>
```

Comment: better use `display: inline-block;`

Comment: thanks for nice suggestion . but it will not keep the submit buttons above  executions. right ? @luiges90

Comment: I got a solution that if i write that html code in php, then submit buttons is showing above execution. 
but it is too disgusting to write echo echo every time.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep the submit buttons above executions"? PHP code are run sequentially (if there is no if/while etc...) and switching to HTML does not change that.

Answer (score 0):

Two different form with horizontal align :

**HTML**

```
<form action=""  method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_action" value="1">
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="[PUSH IT]" name="Submit">
</form>
<form action=""  method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action2" value="1">
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="[AGAIN]" name="Submit">
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
form { float: left; }
```

Comment: thanks. but it will not keep the submit buttons above  executions. right ? @Foxbot

Comment: I got a solution that if i write that html code in php, then submit buttons is showing above execution. 
but it is too disgusting to write echo echo every time.

Answer (score 0):

//TRY THIS

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitOne']))
    {
        echo "submit one done";
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['submitTwo']))
    {
        echo "submit two done";
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="submitOne" value="submitOne"  />
    <input type="submit" name="submitTwo" value="submitTwo"  />
</form>
```

Comment: I have checked . But , my php execution will be above on buttons.

Comment: I got a solution that if i write that html code in php, then submit buttons is showing above execution. 
but it is too disgusting to write echo echo every time.

Comment: @slash-bang : Now you got it